# Getting data from mondrian.olap.Result

Tags: java, mondrian

I want to store the values of result set in a variable. Please someone help me.
Here is my code.

```
mondrian.rolap.RolapConnection connection=(RolapConnection) 
RGHelper.getMDXConnection();
Query query = connection.parseQuery(topNUtilisedRG);

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
Result result = connection.execute(query);
```

i tried to get the result using

```
final Cell cell = result.getCell( new int[]{0,0} );
```

I am using eclipse debugging and I found that all records which I need are present in "cell" variable. But I don't know how to fetch data.

*In this Image I mentioned Values which I want save in some variable:*
[image: In this Image I mentioned Values which I want save in some variable]

[I have gone through this site, but I didn't get the right solution **strong text**](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=mondrian.olap.Cell)

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate trough all cells. If you want get value from current cell you can call getValue()

```
result.getCell( new int[]{0,0} ).getValue()
```

But to get all values you must iterate like that:

```
          Axis[] axes = result.getAxes();          
          int[] pos = new int[2];
          pos[1] = 0;
          for (Position position : axes[1].getPositions())
          {
             for (int i=0; i< axes[0].getPositions().size(); i++)
             {
                pos[0] = i;
                result.getCell(pos).getValue();
             }
             pos[1] += 1;
          }
```